# Dynamically creating a datatable in dc.js using a deeply nested json

Tags: javascript, json, datatable, dc.js, crossfilter

I want to create a datatable using dc.js.  My javascript code is as follows:

```
dataTable.width(800).height(800)
.dimension(collegeDimension)
.group(function(d) { return "List of all Selected Students"
 })
.size(100)
.columns([
    function(d) { return d.student_name; },
    function(d) { return d.student_grade; }
])
.sortBy(function(d){ return d.order-details.order-id; })
// (optional) sort order, :default ascending
.order(d3.ascending);
```

I  have a json file which looks something like this :

```
[{  
  "college_name":"abc",
  "college_students":[  
     {  
        "student_name":"xyz1",
        "student_grade":"A"
     },
     {  
        "student_name":"xyz2",
        "student_grade":"B"
     }
  ]},{  
  "college_name":"abc1",
  "college_students":[  
     {  
        "student_name":"xyz3",
        "student_grade":"A"
     },
     {  
        "student_name":"xyz4",
        "student_grade":"B"
     }
  ]},{  
  "college_name":"abc2",
  "college_students":[  
     {  
        "student_name":"xyz5",
        "student_grade":"A"
     },
     {  
        "student_name":"xyz6",
        "student_grade":"B"
     }
  ]}]
```

I have a requirement where I cannot change the structure of the json.

Is it possible to parse the data and create a data table that has the following structure using dataTable?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone was wondering, I actually solved the problem although it is a sort of a hack . I went with this approach since my datatable was linked to other charts and graphs on my page and needed to update dynamically as a filter took place on the other charts.  So though **Gordon's** answer did solve my problem of handling the data by allowing me to turn the data flat, I still had to combine the two crossfilters that get created.

```
dataTable.width(800).height(800)
.dimension(collegeDimension)
.transitionDuration(1000)
.group(function(d) { return "List of all Selected Students"
 })
.size(100)
.columns(
    [
        function(d) { 
            studs = []; 
            for(var i=0;i<d.college_students.length;i++)
            {
                console.log(d.college_students[i].student_name);
                studs += d.college_students[i].student_name+"<br\>"; 
            }
            return studs;
        },
        function(d) { 
            studs = []; 
            for(var i=0;i<d.college_students.length;i++)
            {
                console.log(d.college_students[i].student_grade);
                studs += d.college_students[i].student_grade+"<br\>"; 
            }
            return studs;
        }
    ])
// (optional) sort order, :default ascending
.order(d3.ascending);
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for sharing your solution. That looks pretty optimal given your constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Your life with crossfilter will be a lot easier if you flatten out the data, but you can pretty easily do that in a pre-processing step without changing the source data:

```
var dd = /* your data */;
var all_students = [];
dd.forEach(function(college) {
    college.college_students.forEach(function(student) {
        all_students.push({college_name: college.college_name, student_name: student.student_name, student_grade: student.student_grade});
    });
});
```

Now use `all_students` for your crossfilter and you won't have to struggle with complicated accessors and so on.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer . I actually solved the problem though it is a little bit of a hack . I will post my answer as well. Thanks again for your help. Cheers

Comment: I could not go ahead with your approach due to reasons I have explained in my answer.

Comment: @gordon - thanks for the observation about flattening. I have been struggling  with deep source data. ill flatten it as step 1.